# Side-by-side display of proposed duplicates in flag review

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions, review, 10k-tools

OK, so I'm lazy.

But it would streamline things a little bit if I could click on a button and have a div popup with side-by-side display of a question and it's flagged duplicate. Not sure about including answers, but maybe some statistic of number of answers on each.

[image]

While I'm being lazy, the popup could also save me having to think, with something like (too lazy to update my screenshot for this, sorry):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Oldest              |           X            |                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Most voted          |                        |         X         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Most answers        |           X            |                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Answers * votes     |                        |         X         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Calculated Quality  |          32            |         75        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Usually duplicates are written differently but have the same purpose/meaning behind them so such thing won't really help in most cases.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd, I have trouble parsing that. Does that mean there's no point comparing them, so I just flag on, or is it not even worth showing them in flag review?

Comment: We need logical comparison, there's no way with simple code or algorithm. What you mean by "just flag on"?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd, edited to 'side-by-side display', maybe that's clearer? I wasn't suggesting an algorithm, I was just suggesting it's easier to click once and stay in context than do two `Ctrl-clicks` followed by *n* `Ctrl-(Shift)-Tabs`

Comment: Yes, this would be great! I am lazy, too, and I see nothing wrong with that lifestyle.

Comment: Upvote me to 10k and I'll write a userscript for this ;-)