# Some ideas for making the flag queue more manageable

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, flag-queue

*(Given the popularity of [my previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133394/130064), I thought I'd spin off the 'positive' bits here, for more constructive discussion.)*

Here are a few ideas for making the 10k flag queue more manageable (or even, more fun?):

- Give me those flags in buckets, by type (right now I'm not interested in dupes)
- Let me filter out the old stuff
- Limit flags based on queue length (like we do with edit suggestions)?
- [Better tools for checking dupes really are dupes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132075/side-by-side-display-of-proposed-duplicates-in-flag-review)
- Give me some way to say 'ignore' - and have the flag disappear from my list, at least

Comment: And, why are some flag comments greyed-out?

Comment: This means those flags were previously raised, then handled, then raised again by someone else. (Or if there's only one name, then most likely the same person is trying to harass us with flags.)

Comment: And yes, the "close question" category could use a more fine-grained breakdown. Bill the Lizard has posted about that in particular, as we share the same set of flag categories as 10k users do (except "other" flags, of course): [Add more grouping/sorting links to the moderator flag queue for “close” and “other” flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127750/add-more-grouping-sorting-links-to-the-moderator-flag-queue-for-close-and-oth)

Comment: No ***way*** should global total number of flags be limited. Absolutely _in favor_ of "ignore" button.